# Не работает скрипт в IE11

Tags: javascript, ie11

Есть js-код, который всем iframe задает атрибут src. Но в IE11 он не срабатывает.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
document.querySelectorAll("iframe[name=form_reg]").forEach(function callback(frame, index, array) {
            frame.setAttribute("src", "https://domain.link/form/i/?type=landing&prelanding=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname) + "&" + location.search.substring(1));
        });
```

Comment: разбивать и по кусочкам смотреть не получалось?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема тут

```
iframe[name='form_reg']
```

Comment: Хм.. И это тоже, но вроде оно и в других браузерах не должно работать? UPDATE: Chrome вполне ест.

Comment: согласен и с Вами тоже

Answer (score 0):

1. В консоли должно быть написано.
2. Вроде бы в IE у этой коллекции нет метода `forEach`.

Полифил

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        thisArg = thisArg || window;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Да и это тоже https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Объединим ответы?

Comment: Да вроде и так нормально.